# How to use a variable in the query string of pd.read_sql_query?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a python script that runs a few SQL queries. However, the table being queried will change on a semi-regular basis. To make the script more user-friendly I want to store the table name in a variable.

The code I have so far looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

V_pct = "UACO_PCT0000003221"

V_contact_df = pd.read_sql_query(
sql = """"
SELECT DATE(CONTACTDATETIME) AS CONTACT_DATE
FROM AF.{V_pct}
GROUP BY DATE(CONTACTDATETIME);
""",
con = V_conn)
```

V_conn is my connection to the database I'm querying; I've left out the code that sets this up to make things easier to read. AF is the name of the schema the table sits in. The database is DB2.

When I run the code above I get this error:

```
Exception: Statement Execute Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0010N  The string constant beginning with ""     SELECT DATE(CONTACTDATETIME) AS CONTACT_DATE     FROM AF.{V_pct}" does not have an ending string delimit SQLCODE=-10E=42603
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: You need `f` before the string to make it an f-string so that variables will be replaced.

Comment: Aside - *table being queried will change on a semi-regular basis* .... this is questionable database design. Suffixed tables should be normalized. Talk to DB developer or maintainer.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait! Just to clarify, it's not one table whose name changes; I probably phrased this badly. It's a series of tables with datestamps created by another process. The script I'm trying to write is intended to run some checks on whatever the latest table is.